# How can I show that the acceleration vector for uniform circular motion undergoes uniform rotation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, differentiation

Does it suffice to show that the dot product between the acceleration vector and the derivative of the acceleration vector = 0?

Comment: it is uniform circular motion(so, it will have only normal component of accelaration present i.e, centripital accelaration , in it with tangential accelaration zero at every instant)  so, derivative of accelaration vector don't make any sense

Comment: \begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}\left(t\right)=\rho\left(\cos\omega t,\sin\omega t\right)\quad
\Longrightarrow \quad
\left.
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\left(t\right)=\dfrac{\rm d\mathbf{r}}{\rm dt}=\rho\omega\left(-\sin\omega t,\cos\omega t\right)\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\mathbf{a}\left(t\right)=\dfrac{\rm d\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{\rm dt}=\boldsymbol{-}\rho\omega^{2}\left(\cos\omega t,\sin\omega t\right)=\boldsymbol{-}\omega^{2}\mathbf{r}\left(t\right)
\end{cases}\!\right\}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polar coordinate unit vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ are related to the cartesian coordinates with $\hat r = \cos \theta \hat i + \sin \theta \hat j$ and $\hat \theta = -\sin \theta \hat i + \cos \theta \hat j$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{d \hat r}{d \theta}= -\sin \theta \hat i + \cos \theta \hat j = \hat \theta$
$\Rightarrow \dfrac{d\hat r}{dt} = \dfrac{d \hat r}{d \theta}\,\dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \dfrac{d\theta}{dt} \hat \theta= \dot \theta \hat \theta$
For uniform circular motion the acceleration is $\vec a= - \dfrac {v^2}{r} \hat r$ with $v$ and $r$ constant.
You can differentiate the expression for $\vec a$ with respect to time and obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

in general in any curvilinear motion

tangential accelaration i.e, $\vec a_{t}$(which is responsible for change of speed of particle) = component of $\vec a$ along$\vec v$ $\vec a_{t}=|a|cos\theta=\dfrac{\vec a.\vec v}{|v|}\tag1$

whereas total accelaration is vector sum of tangential and normal accelaration vectors i.e,

$\vec a=\vec a_{t}+\vec a_{n}$

also $\vec a_{t}=\dfrac{d|v|}{dt}$=rate of change of speed

but in U.C.M

$\dfrac{d|v|}{dt}=0\implies a_{t}=0$

and hence from eq. $(1)$

$\vec a. \vec v=0 $

**Coclusion**: In U.C.M dot product of total accelaration vector with velocity vector (not the derivative of accelaration vector as you have written in question) is zero